# Dropdown Menu Works HTML Issue when PHP includes

Tags: php, html, css

The issue is that when the dropdown menu is clicked, no menu comes down. Before using PHP's include, the menu worked as it should.

At first, each .html page contained its own navigation bar code. However, I recently discovered PHP's "include" function. I copied the portion of code for the nav bar to navigation.php and used the PHP include statement in index.php (the original .html page). I have removed much of the unnecessary code:

```
<?php include("includes/navigation.php"); ?>
```

This is the only line of code within my index.php file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Invest for Hope - Donations</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<link rel="icon" href="/assets/favicon.ico">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/assets/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/assets/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/assets/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"> 
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style type="text/css">html,body{height:100%;}.container-full{margin:0 auto;width:100%;min-height:100%;background-color:#110022;color:#eee;overflow:hidden;}.container-full a{color:#efefef;text-decoration:none;}.v-center{margin-top:7%;}[class^="cus-"],[class*=" cus-"]{display:inline-block;width:17px;height:16px;*margin-right:.3em;line-height:14px;vertical-align:text-top;background-image:url("/assets/social-icons-nav.png");background-position:14px 14px;background-repeat:no-repeat;opacity:0.5;}[class^="cus-"]:last-child,[class*=" cus-"]:last-child{*margin-left:0;}[class^="cus-"]:hover,[class*=" cus-"]:hover{opacity:1;}.cus-social-email{background-position:0 0;width:24px;height:24px;}.cus-social-facebook{background-position:-29px 0;width:24px;height:24px;}.cus-social-twitter{background-position:-58px 0;width:24px;height:24px;}.cus-social-youtube{background-position:-87px 0;width:24px;height:24px;}.btn-xlmain{width:310px;height:18px%;position:absolute;text-align:center;left:0;right:0;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;z-index:51;margin-top:-50px;}</style>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> About<b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="mission.html"> About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="team.html"> Team</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

This is all the code after removing most of it from the navigation.php file. Now, it only includes the dropdown menu and CSS to format the page.

If you want to view the actual issue with the dropdown menu, go to [www.investforhope.org](http://www.investforhope.org). The homepage is the display of the exact code I have shown.

Comment: So where in `index.php` is the include of `includes/navigation.php`

Comment: It seems that you have some troubles with HTML comments <!--commented code-->

Comment: why did you use your own css when you are using bootstarp

Comment: What are you actually asking here? Is it that you dont know where to put the PHP include?

Comment: Press STRG+U, is this intended?

Comment: The index.php only has one line of code, which is the PHP include statement. The only issue is that the dropdown menu won't function correctly. When it's clicked, the menu doesn't come down. Sorry for the ambiguity of my question, I'll edit it.

Comment: You had better show the `navigation.php` code as well or is that what you have shown in the code section???

Comment: Cagatay Ulubay, no it's not, thanks for pointing that out. RiggsFolly, the second section of code is the navigation.php code.

Comment: I think you will find there is a little more to PHP than you realise. Maybe you would be better checking if your server has SSI (Server side includes) activated and use that instead.

Comment: I think you have not included bootstrap js file. Try to include it and then check it.

Comment: Some serious but very basic errors caused by someone whom they should not have let loose on their live website.

Comment: @JoshTheLiuser you've massively broken that website. Give it over to someone who knows what they're doing.

Comment: @NigelAngel My co-worker doesn't know HTML. He broke the website's code, so I'm trying to fix it. I know it's terrible, and I agree. Thanks!

Comment: @JoshTheLiuser but you are making it worse. It will take a  developer minutes to fix properly.

Comment: @NigelAngel can you help please? I would really appreciate it. I'm not sound at all in HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the source of the link you gave. You've commented out all your JS includes by omitting the closing comment tag used to remove `.modal-dialog`.
Undo that error by adding the close comment marker `-->` after `.modal-dialog`'s closing tag and it will work.

This is what you have

```
<!--
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    ...
    <script ... >
    ...
    </body>
</html>
```

no close-comment tag (though the browser may render one).

This is what you should have, where `</div>` is the matching closing tag.

```
<!--
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    ...
    </div> 
-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
etc etc
```

**ALSO** this line that isn't helping at all.

```
<script>"js/bootstrap.js"</script>
```

Comment: I actually included all the commented out code in navigation.php. Thanks for the help though! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add JQuery and Bootstrap javascript in your page.

download them or using a CDN to do a quick test, add following line in your HTML, inner `<header>` :

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Look at the source. OP thinks they have

Comment: @Popnoodles I've tested in his webpage in adding these two JS and it works. I'm sure that's the reason

Comment: Actually thats a good point, he has only included the CSS and nothing else for bootstrap

Comment: No he included the JS then commented it out.

Comment: Thank you. That solved everything.

Comment: No it didn't solve it. It put a band-aid over a major problem caused by a simple thing. You're just destroying the website. Let someone fix it for you because while it appears to work to the layman, it's now very very broken.

Comment: @Popnoodles, I know it's broken. My co-worker doesn't know HTML at all, so he just copies and pastes code. I'm just trying to fix the errors he's made. Also, I'm learning the different languages as I'm trying to solve the many issues. Thanks for the input!

Comment: There aren't many issues. Please have someone who already knows those languages fix it. You're working on a live site, figuring it out as you go, and getting it very wrong.

Comment: @Popnoodles thanks, really appreciate the help! If you know HTML pretty well, could you possibly take a look and just fix a few things? That would be great!

Comment: I do and I already explained the problem; Someone commented things out and didn't close their comment tags. With that VERY SIMPLE thing fixed, the problem you posted a question about would not need fixing because it wouldn't exist. The javascript is commented out - you're now trying to putting it back instead of uncommenting what shouldn't be commented. Find where the comment should be closed, and close it.

Comment: @Popnoodles the commented out portion is found in another .php file. I included everything by copying and pasting it over. I just commented it out in order to keep it available, in case something went terribly wrong with the new .php file. The temporary solution works for now, but is there anything else that's wrong? The comments shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: **The comments ARE the issue.** You unintentionally commented out ALL the javascript files, and now you're adding those files back in separately! Your HTML is now a mess, which can be easily fixed by simply understanding what you've done and using comments correctly. The commented out portion may be in another file but they all get collated and outputted as ONE HTML file. They can affect each other, and you've proven that they do.

Comment: @Popnoodles Thank you so much. I was wrong. You were right. I added the commented portion into the footer.php, which is another that I'm including within the index.php. Now everything works great. Really appreciate the help!